# Drawing on screen - Java

Tags: java, drawing

I want to draw and update positions of some simple shapes (like line, circle or rectangle) on the screen in Java.
For example I want to have circle around cursor. I can get the position of the cursor with Robot, and then how to draw? Is there some simple way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're specifically asking how to draw *outside of a Java window* -- and I think you are -- then you should try to rephrase your question to make that clearer.

Comment: I don't have any Java window.

Comment: Yes I Googled. But I didn't find anything easy and short, and this look like easy and short problem. I don't want to read the whole turorials.

Comment: I would suggest reading whole tutorials. It is a quick way to get a lot of great information. Admitting you dont want to do these things does not encourage others to help you.

Comment: You can answer the same thing to many other questions here. In fact for all how to questions. I was googling this for 15-20 minutes and I coundn't find the answer so I asked it here. This is what this page is for.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very BROAD question. You should look at the [Java2D Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html), they should give you a start.

Answer (score 1):

For shapes and pictures there are few tutorials on internet if you google, i think java tutorial under oracle docs are good for starters - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html

or

here http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Java2D-Tutorial.html

Secondly these tutorials are just to give you guideline I recommend you reading a book for Java 2d/3d graphics, thats how you will have good understanding of graphic concepts.